# Regex Pattern matching refinement

Tags: regex, linux, grep

I have a json that is returned to a variable, I'm trying to only grab values of from the json. I'm only limited to grep, sed, and awk

```
RESULTS='{ "results" : [ { "repo" : "appdeploy", "path" : "org/test/cxp/python/1.0-SNAPSHOT", "name" : "python-1.0-20170519.130808-42.jar" } ], "range" : { "start_pos" : 0, "end_pos" : 1, "total" : 1 } }'
echo $RESULTS | grep -o '"path" : "(.*)",'
```

returns me the result

```
"path" : "org/test/cxp/python/1.0-SNAPSHOT",
```

and honestly the only part I want is

```
org/test/cxp/python/1.0-SNAPSHOT
```

Comment: It is better to parse out JSON values with [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/), but in case you need to use `grep`, try `grep -oP '(?<="path" : ")[^"]+'`

Comment: yeah I don't have access to `jq`. I'll try what you suggested. Thanks!

Comment: Perfect! Thanks!

Comment: I was checking the correct filter in `jq` for this. I will post the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/), you could use `'.results[0] | .path'` filter. You may play around with [this tool online here](https://jqplay.org/).

However, if you have no access to `jq`, you may use a PCRE based `grep` command like

```
grep -oP '(?<="path" : ")[^"]+'
```

The `-P` option enables the PCRE regex syntax usage where you may use [*lookarounds*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) that only check for the pattern match, but do not include the matched text into the returned match value.

**Pattern details**

- `(?<="path" : ")` - a positive lookbehind that matches a *position* that is preceded with `"path" : "` substring
- `[^"]+` - a negated bracket expression that matches and *consumes* (adds to the match value) 1 or more chars other than `"`.

See the [online `grep` demo](https://ideone.com/FDHy70):

```
RESULTS='{ "results" : [ { "repo" : "appdeploy", "path" : "org/test/cxp/python/1.0-SNAPSHOT", "name" : "python-1.0-20170519.130808-42.jar" } ], "range" : { "start_pos" : 0, "end_pos" : 1, "total" : 1 } }'
echo $RESULTS | grep -oP '(?<="path" : ")[^"]+'
```

Printing `org/test/cxp/python/1.0-SNAPSHOT`.

Comment: I think I found a new tool ideone.com I was trying to use regex101.com which gave me the start of what I was working with but `grep` regex wasn't matching the same as regex101

Comment: Regex101 is a great site, but 1) it supports PHP/JS/Python and Go regex syntax only and 2) it has its own bugs/limitations that one should be aware of. The site can be used to see how this or that pattern works, but to see if a pattern is working or not, it must be tested in the target environment.@ndrone: If it works for you, please consider accepting upvoting.

Answer (score 0):

here you go, using both grep and sed:

```
echo $RESULTS | grep -op '"path" :\s"[^"]*"' | sed 's/"//g' | sed 's/path : //g'
```

This works first by doing `echo $RESULTS | grep -op '"path" :\s"[^"]*"'` which produces `"path" : "org/test/cxp/python/1.0-SNAPSHOT"` then the first call to `sed 's/"//g'` strips out the double quotes and the second call `sed 's/path : //g'` strips out `path :`

Answer (score 0):

It is best to use a JSON parser for these type things.

Python, Ruby, Perl all have robust JSON parsers available.

Here is an example in Python:

```
$ python -c '
import json
import fileinput

print json.loads("".join(line for line in fileinput.input()))["results"][0]["path"]
' <<<$(echo "$RESULTS")
org/test/cxp/python/1.0-SNAPSHOT
```